# how to add columns in existing table based on other tables using pandas or sql query

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

What is the best way to create columns in existing table i data-base....

So now ...
I have 3 different tables in database as the below tables:

`àll_sites`

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        Vendor       |     ops_num      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         a           |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         b           |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         a           |         3        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         b           |         4        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         b           |         5        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         a           |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         a           |         7        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

`umts_carrier_mnm`

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        ops_num      |     cell_name    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |         11       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |         12       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         1           |         13       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         2           |         21       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         2           |         22       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         2           |         23       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         3           |         31       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

So Now I need to add more 2 columns `vendor` and 'ops_num' in the below table:

`umts_df_relation`

```
|---------------------|
|        cell_name    |
|---------------------|
|         11          |
|---------------------|
|         12          |
|---------------------|
|         13          |
|---------------------|
|         21          |
|---------------------|
|         22          |
|---------------------|
|         23          |
|---------------------|
|         31          |
|---------------------|
```

So I want to add 2 columns `ops_num` and 'vendor' in the previous table as the result to be like this as the below table:

`umts_df_relation`

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        cell_name    |     ops_num      |     vendor       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         11          |         1        |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         12          |         1        |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         13          |         1        |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         21          |         2        |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         22          |         2        |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         23          |         2        |         b        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         31          |         3        |         a        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So this the query I want to be like as the below query:
`alter table [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation] add vendor varchar , ops_num INT`

Now I need to fill the new columns with the va;ues related to other tables

So is there's any way to `ALTER` table using query or pandas?, and what is better way to solve this, and how?

Thanks for support

Comment: `ALTER` is a type of query. What about the `ALTER` statement don't you understand, and why isn't it working?

Comment: @Larnu I need to use `ALTER` query or do this function by pandas...
I don't know how to do it

Comment: Ok, so "What about the `ALTER` statement don't you understand"? What in the documentation confused you?

Comment: @Larnu I don't know what's the right sequence to make a query do this

Comment: Ok, but you've still not told me what you don't understand. What in the documentation is confusing you? There are examples as well in the documentation, and plenty on Stack Overflow, so what about those didn't show you was the correct syntax?

Comment: @Larnu if you have docs for this case please send me or help me to do this funtion...
thank you for your support :)
I understand the ALTER Query, but I don't know how to create those 2 columns related to the other tables :)...

Thank  you for you help!!!

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of another question, that shows you how to use `ALTER`. if you don't understand, then I suggest posting a new question, showing us why what you've tried doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: *"if you have docs for this case please send me or help me to do this funtion"* Your favourite search engine will find these for you *very* quickly; SQL Server's documentation is very extensive. That should always be your first port of call.

Comment: @Larnu okay I'll try to use `ALTER` query then I'll back to you :)

Comment: @Larnu Now I created the 2 columns I need with this query `alter table [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation] add vendor varchar , ops_num INT` So now how can I fill those columns with values related to others tables? please check edit

Comment: That's a completely different question, and should be asked as one. I, however, suggest looking up the `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @Larnu yes actually I am using something like this query `UPDATE [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation] 
SET [myDB].[dbo].[umts_df_relation].[ops_num] = [myDB].[dbo].[all_sites].[ops_num]
WHERE Condition` but I stucked now On condition that's for one column only :)...
I am trying to figure it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207095/discussion-between-mahmoud-al-haroon-and-larnu).